# proto3 encoding - struct vs marshaled struct

Tags: encoding, protocol-buffers, proto3

I wish to know if there could be any significant difference in terms of mem efficiency between marshaling a struct and marshaling a marshaled struct.

Example:
Assume we have a struct B with some fields.

```
message B{...}
```

The common representation:

```
message A {
    B b = 1;
}
```

Another way:

```
message A {
    bytes b = 1;
}
```

Where b is a marshaled B struct.

Generally, is it a good practice? any efficiency implications?

Thanks,
Elad

Comment: minor point - note that there's no such thing as "proto3 encoding" - the encoding hasn't changed at all in the public protobuf time; "proto3" relates only to the DSL syntax, and doesn't impact the encoding at all.

Answer (score 1):

At the payload level, they are identical - however, in terms of how implementations *treat them*, there may be differences. The most *obvious* difference is that you can't use a `bytes` until you further deserialize it; this has pros and cons:

- if you weren't ever going to touch it anyway, this could be fine and advantageous - avoiding some CPU processing that you didn't need for read or write; this will also mean that any downstream allocations (strings, etc) don't need to happen - so you only have a single allocation chunk: easy and efficient
- if you *do* need to read it, then in addition to making life less convenient, you could have allocated an extra chunk of memory for the *raw* form (a chunk of bytes), *and* you'll need to allocate for the deserialized form; if you went *straight* to the deserialized form, most implementations would have skipped that intermediate allocation

So: yes, it will have different characteristics. Whether they are advantageous (or the opposite) depends on whether you also need to do the extra deserialization step on the `bytes` payload

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bad practice to declare a `bytes` field instead of a struct you would have otherwise specified in a proto file.

It's called a specification hole: you will have to write an additional documentation to describe how the receiver has to understand the bytes